# TFS Build Automation - How to drop builds into development environment on separate domain

Tags: build-automation, tfsbuild

We have TFS 2013 installed on a domain called "MyCompany".  It has build automation configured and the build server is also on the "MyCompany" domain.

In our company we develop on a separate domain called "MyCompanyDEV".

What we want to do is have the build automation process drop build somewhere on the "MyCompanyDEV" domain so it's accessible to developers without them having to go have someone pull it out of the drop folder on the "MyCompany" domain.

I know you can drop builds directly into TFS but I dont see this as a great solution since it will take space in the database.

Can someone point me in the right direction to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a one way trust level between the dev and main domains? i.e. does MyCompanyDEV trust the MyCompany domain?

Comment: @RichardBanks No, it does not. MyCompanyDEV has no connection to MyCompany.

Answer (score 1):

I use TFS to deploy to test servers in a different domain where there is no trust. The trick is to create a 'shadow' account i.e. create an account in MyCompanyDEV with exactly the same name AND password as the account your build service runs under in MyCompany. So if your TFS build account is:

MyCompany\svcTFSBuild

Then also create:

MyCompanyDEV\svcTFSBuild (with the same password as above)

I dont see why this wouldnt work in your scenario, just use the I.P. address of the target server in your build definition drop location setting

Answer (score 0):

In the build definition under the Build/Advanced you have the option to specify the post-build action. You should set this option to a script that is copying the build output to the location of the other domain (MyCompanyDEV)